# Spree sagepay cv2 code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree, opayo

I'm using spree version 1.3.2 and am using the standard spree gateway for payment, everything works except the cv2 code is not being submitted to sagepay when a payment is made, any ideas on where I can look? I would post code but it's not modified and I wouldn't know where to look, any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spree Gateway uses ActiveMerchant to assist in communications with Sage Pay.  The code which adds the CV2 value to the Sage Pay request is located here:

https://github.com/Shopify/active_merchant/blob/v1.29.3/lib/active_merchant/billing/gateways/sage_pay.rb#L202

You can find your ActiveMerchant code location by executing:

```
bundle show activemerchant
```

and add in some debugging there.  If you follow the stack trace up, you should be able to find where the credit card object is coming from, and why it's not being populated with the correct value from the Spree credit card.